# Linq Insert problem for Beginners

Tags: linq, insert

Why is this thing not working?

```
[Database(Name="Relationships_Test")]
[Table(Name = "Order")]
public class Order
{
 [Column(Name="ID", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
 public int ID { get; set; }

 [Column(Name = "OrderDate")]
 public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

 public void Save()
 {
  DataContext dc = new DataContext(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Relationships_Test;Integrated Security=True");

  dc.ExecuteCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Order] (ID,OrderDate) VALUES (@ID,@OrderDate)", this.ID, this.OrderDate);
 }
}


    Order o = new Order();
o.ID = 3;
    o.OrderDate = DateTime.Parse("12/31/2999");
    o.Save();
```

This code generates an exception

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write it like this

`dc.ExecuteCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Order] (ID,OrderDate) VALUES ({0}, {1})", this.ID, this.OrderDate);`

[Check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx)

It says

> This method is a pass-through
>   mechanism for cases where LINQ to SQL
>   does not adequately provide for a
>   particular scenario.
>
> The syntax for the command is almost
>   the same as the syntax used to create
>   an ADO.NET DataCommand. The only
>   difference is in how the parameters
>   are specified. Specifically, you
>   specify parameters by enclosing them
>   in braces ({…}) and enumerate them
>   starting from 0. The parameter is
>   associated with the equally numbered
>   object in the parameters array.
>
> The following example opens a
>   connection and passes a SQL UPDATE
>   command to the SQL engine.